# c++ can't call subclass methode using a pointer to the class

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a Vector `vector c_<class A * >;` declared as private in some class. This vector holds pointers to subclasses of A. So for example:

```
some_class::func {
    c_.push_back (new A2);  // same as A1.
    c_.push_back (new A1);  //A1 is subclass : class A1 : public A;
    (c_.back()->methode1(); //returns a reference of A1's private member x_ for example 
}
```

The error I get is: no such method defined in class A.
Offcourse it's not decleared in class A it's declared in class A1. The way I see is that `c_.back` gets the last element in the vector c_. This is a pointer to class A1, so I dereference it with: -> and call methode1() in the class where the pointer points to(A1). But I get an error, but I don't get where it goes wrong.

Comment: `vector c_<class A * >` I doubt it

Comment: `This vector holds pointers to subclasses of A` Why?

Comment: This also wont work for the same reason: `A *a = new A1; a->methode1();`. The problem is that `methode1` is not part of `A`'s interface.

Comment: @ Lightness: I want to keep them both in the same vector because I need to add, insert, sort on id for example, delete and acces them easely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access `A` methods from a pointer to `A`. In order to call an `A1` method on an element of `c_`, you would have to cast to `A1`, or re-think your design.

```
A1* a1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(c_.back());
if (a1) a1->methode1();
```

The vector is just a distraction. You have the equivalent of this:

```
A* a = new A1();
a->methode1();  // Error, A has no methode1()

A1* a1 = dynamic_cast<A1*>(a);
if (a1) a1->methode1(); // OK, call the method only if the cast succeeded.
```

In general, it is not a good sign if you find yourself performing these casts too often.

Comment: C_ stores pointers to A1 and A2. What I want to do is, use the pointer stored in C_ to call a getter in A1 or A2 to get private values from A1 or A2.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm able to do what you do and it works. But it's impossible to call an A1 method when I put the pointers in the c_ vector and get them out with c_.back(). I get the same error: method not defined in A. When I do it your way, I don't get an error and it returns the right result

Comment: @user2321611 exactly. As I said, you cannot call `A1` methods from an `A` pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza nvm got it :D I forgot to cast the pointer I get from the vector.